# Devexpress PictureEdit Cropping issue

Tags: c#, winforms, image, devexpress

I have a image that is larger than the PictureEdit box issue is when the Rectangle is created with the mouse the correct points on the image are not selected. It seems that it is selecting points in the PictureEdit not the image it self.  I'm trying to crop the image and place the cropped image in a new Pictureedit. Example code below.

```
private void originalPictureEdit_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //Point TextStartLocation = e.Location;
    Cursor = Cursors.IBeam;

    if (_drawStarted == false)
    {
        _drawStarted = true;

        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Cursor = Cursors.Cross;

            _cropX = e.X;
            _cropY = e.Y;
            _selection = new Rectangle(new Point(e.X, e.Y), new Size());
            _cropPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
            _cropPen.DashStyle = DashStyle.DashDotDot;
        }
    }

    originalPictureEdit.Refresh();
}

private void originalPictureEdit_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

    if (originalPictureEdit.Image == null)
        return;

    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        originalPictureEdit.Refresh();
        _selection.Width = e.X - _selection.X;
        _selection.Height = e.Y - _selection.Y;
        originalPictureEdit.CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle(_cropPen, _cropX, _cropY, _selection.Width, _selection.Height);

    }          
}

private void originalPictureEdit_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && _drawStarted && _selection.Size != new Size())
     {
         _croppedImage = (_displayedImage as Bitmap).Clone(_selection, _displayedImage.PixelFormat);

         modifiedPictureEdit.Image = _croppedImage;
         modifiedPictureEdit.Width = _croppedImage.Width;
         modifiedPictureEdit.Height = _croppedImage.Height;   
     }

     Cursor = Cursors.Default;

     _drawStarted = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to find the positions of the scrollbars. Here is the working code for MouseUp:

```
private void pictureEdit1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
       if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && _drawStarted && _selection.Size != new Size())
       {
            PictureEditViewInfo viewInfo = originalPictureEdit.GetViewInfo() as PictureEditViewInfo;
            PropertyInfo pr = viewInfo.GetType().GetProperty("HScrollBarPosition", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            int fHScrollBarPosition = (int)pr.GetValue(viewInfo, null);
            pr = viewInfo.GetType().GetProperty("VScrollBarPosition", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            int fVScrollBarPosition = (int)pr.GetValue(viewInfo, null);
            _selection.X += fHScrollBarPosition;
            _selection.Y += fVScrollBarPosition;

            Crop();
        }

        Cursor = Cursors.Default;

        _drawStarted = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [PictureEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsPictureEdittopic) control can display image with offset or zoom, so you should accept these factors in your calculation. I believe the following approach may helps you:

```
PictureEditViewInfo viewInfo = GetViewInfo(originalPictureEdit);
Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(
    _selection.X - viewInfo.PictureStartX,
    _selection.Y - viewInfo.PictureStartY,
    _selection.Width,
    _selection.Height);
_croppedImage = (originalPictureEdit.Image as Bitmap).Clone(cropRect,
    originalPictureEdit.Image.PixelFormat);
//...
static PictureEditViewInfo GetViewInfo(PictureEdit edit) {
    PropertyInfo pInfo = typeof(BaseEdit).GetProperty("ViewInfo",
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    return (PictureEditViewInfo)pInfo.GetValue(edit, new object[] { });
}
```

Also I recommend you replace the direct drawing on pictureedit graphich with the following:

```
//...
Point frameLocation = originalPictureEdit.PointToScreen(_selection.Location);
ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(
    new Rectangle(frameLocation, _selection.Size), Color.Black, FrameStyle.Dashed);
```